# Rails' validates_confirmation_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to create a registration form (just for practice) and saw this method for rails and want to use it. However, I am quite confused on how I should use this. I have fields where each corresponds to an attribute in the database. Like I have
text_field_tag(:username) and  my model has t.string :username. For password confirmation, I have the password attribute in the model, but I do not have the confirmation attribute. I am wondering how I should go about doing this so that Rails will check for the right field. What should I name the confirmation field?
is it just password_confirmation? Does this happen by convention? Can someone elaborate more about this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes _confirmation is a convention that can be overridden  Add

```
attr_accessor :password_confirmation
```

To your model.

Answer (score 0):

The 'confirmation' field is not stored in the database.

The field name *is* just `password_confirmation`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001395